# Debian software allowing me to make ISOs available as package repo over network?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, iso

I have used jigdo to create the dual-layer BD images for Debian (amd64) and I'd like to use those now to make them available to *all* clients in my home network, if possible, but *without* duplicating the data.

Is there a software that can help me do that *without* having to copy the contents off the (mounted via `losetup` and `mount`) images?

I want a (disk space) economic solution that makes use of the packages from the images instead of having to duplicate all that data.